# Passing Parameters to Create a View in SQL Server using stored procedure - dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create views using stored procedure and passing dynamic SQL in SQL Server.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_businessUnit_totalRequests 
    (@ViewName AS VARCHAR(50),
     @RequiredBU AS VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Req_View_Name AS SYSNAME;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @Req_View_Name = @ViewName

    SET @sql = '
            CREATE VIEW [Req_View_Name]
            As 
            BEGIN
            Select [Reviewer], Count([Reviewer]) as Total_Requests From [dbo].[reviews_not_sent] where [BU] = @RequiredBU  Group By [Reviewer];
            END
            '
            SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '[Req_View_Name]', QUOTENAME(@Req_View_Name));

               EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                           N'@RequiredBU VARCHAR(50)',@RequiredBU=@RequiredBU
        END;

EXEC sp_businessUnit_totalRequests 'Annuities_Requests', 'Annuities';
```

The stored procedure gets created. But when I tried to execute the stored procedure, it says:

> Incorrect Syntax near View

Comment: add `print @sql` and examine the dynamic SQL and compare it to the syntax for CREATE VIEW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You can't create parametrised views. Inside the definition for your view you have `WHERE BU = @RequiredBU`.

Comment: So, parametrised views are just not possible?

Comment: @Sean Lange The View name is dynamic, atleast that's what I think the code is doing.

Comment: Correct. A view is a fixed query to look at the data. If you need parameters you should use a stored procedure.

Comment: *"So, parametrised views are just not possible"* No. You would likely either use a table-value function or Stored Procedure, or you would parametrise the query that references the `VIEW`. I.e. `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyView WHERE ViewColumn = @Variable;`.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_businessUnit_totalRequests] 
                (
                @ViewName AS VARCHAR(50),
                @RequiredBU AS VARCHAR(50)
                )
    AS
    BEGIN

        Declare @Req_View_Name AS SYSNAME;
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

        Set @Req_View_Name = @ViewName

        set @sql = '
        CREATE VIEW [Req_View_Name]
        As 
        Select [Reviewer], Count([Reviewer]) as Total_Requests From [dbo].[reviews_not_sent] where [BU] = ''' + @RequiredBU + '''  Group By [Reviewer];
        '
        SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '[Req_View_Name]', QUOTENAME(@Req_View_Name));

           EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    END;
```

This Code works although it suffers from SQL Injection. Parametrized SQL View creation is not possible.

Comment: Don't just inject the value of `@RequiredBU` in. SQL Injection is a huge problem, and there are no excuses for enabling it in your code.

Comment: I have adjusted the answer to say that, the following code will work but suffers from SQL injection and Parameterized SQL View creation is not possible. At this point, it is waiting on Peer Review.